# How to get dynamic components created in ngfor component outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular11

I have some code that renders a set of components from component type in an ngfor loop

```
  <div class="outlet">
            <app-customer-personal-details [selectedCustomer]="selectedCustomer"></app-customer-personal-details>
            <ng-template *ngFor="let formComponent of (addedFormComponents$ | async); trackBy: formIdAndOrder"
            [ngComponentOutlet]="formComponent.component">
            </ng-template>
  </div>
```

where in the above `formComponent.component` is of `Type<GenericFormComponent>`

When i run it this renders fine and the components are created as they should. But when i try to get a list of those components so i can access the instance i keep getting undefined;

What i have tried to do.

The most obvious

```
    // doesnt work returns empty list
    @ViewChildren(GenericFormComponent) formComponents: QueryList<GenericFormComponent>;
```

Then ive also tried

```
// Doesnt work returns empty list
@ViewChildren(TemplateRef, {read: GenericFormComponent}) formComponents: QueryList<GenericFormComponent>;
```

I have also tried providing an injection token for my components using

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-observation',
    templateUrl: './observation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./observation.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        { provide: GenericFormComponent, useExisting: ObservationComponent }
    ]
})
export class ObservationComponent extends GenericFormComponent implements OnInit {
```

None of this approaches worked.

Is it possible to access the components created using the ngfor ngComponentOutlet?

Note this is on Angular 11.

Answer (score 0):

I put a solution in [this repo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ssyphm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

What you're trying to do can be achieved by dynamically adding components to a `ViewContainerRef`. I had no luck, however, with using `ngComponentOutlet`, my best guess is that Ivy demands the use of 'ahead-of-time type-analysable' templates in order to compile  <sub>it needs to statically analyze your templates</sub>

A word of warning however:
This technique really messes with Ivy, I'm not totally sure but it could lead to problems with AOT/SSR and production builds, so be careful using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately i cant use an answer like this as i want to use Angulars ngfor trackBy function optimiziation of avoiding re-rendering on the dom as the order of my components matter. I tried an approach like this before and i cant store the components and achive want i want but i loose the benefits that come with NgFor optimization.